# How to add SpEL condition for dates in @StreamListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-el

I am able to send messages through Kafka or RabbitMQ and consume them with @StreamListener.

I would like now to skip messages for which one header doesn't meet date conditions.

For example, I would expect someting like this:

```
@StreamListener(value = INPUT, condition = "headers['startDate'] < now()")
public void onMessage(@Payload Data data) { 
    // I process only messages where header "startDate" is before now
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what the header contains.

Assuming it contains a time in milliseconds, use:

```
headers['startDate'] < new java.util.Date().time
```

Comment: Thank you Gary. I have tried but it does not well work. My message is well consumed on startup. But if I publish another message with the same rule, I get the error "Cannot find a @StreamListener matching for message with id: 1234"

Comment: That message will result if the condition returns false.

Comment: That means the message is no longer reprocessed ? In fact I would like to skip the message while the date condition is not True. But it is maybe not possible with stream.

Comment: When using a `condition`, messages are discarded if no `@StreamListener` has a condition that passes. You would need custom code in your listener to do what you want - you would also have to be careful to not suspend the thread longer than the kafka `max.poll.interval.ms`; otherwise Kafka will think the consumer is dead and rebalance the partitions.